# Azure FileStorage CloudFile

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I am trying to programmatically download a file I have just saved into Azure File Storage and I am getting a

> {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}

when I call the DownloadToStream method.  What am doing wrong?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
        var combinedRelativeDirectory = GetCloudDirectory(relativePath);
        CloudFile cloudFile = null;

        cloudFile = combinedRelativeDirectory.GetFileReference(filename);
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        cloudFile.DownloadToStream(memoryStream, AccessCondition.GenerateIfExistsCondition());
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        return memoryStream;
```

Comment: Are you sure if the File exists? Aka `if (cloudFile.Exists()) { .. }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue using your code. By viewing the response message from Fiddler. I found the detail error message is 'Condition headers are not supported.'. After removed the AccessCondition.GenerateIfExistsCondition() parameter, the code could work fine.

```
cloudFile.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
```

If you want to check whether the file is exist before downloading the file, you could use Exists method.

```
if (file.Exists())
{
    file.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out shortly.

Comment: If anyone wants to learn more about troubleshooting Azure Storage, including using Fiddler, check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-e2e-troubleshooting

Comment: I get a compile error : 'IListFileItem' does not conain a defenition for 'DownloadToFile' and no extention method 'DownloadToFile' accepting a first argument of type 'IListFileItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) when I try the download to file line , any ideas to why is that ?